# AngularJs Evaluate an expression against multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to call a function only while 2 conditions are true?

```
<a id="Send" ng-click="(model.condition1 and model.condition2) || doSomething()"></a>
```

Comment: instead of `and` use `&&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should keep logic away from the `template`. But this should work:

```
<a id="Send" 
   ng-click="model.condition1 && model.condition2 && doSomething()"></a>
```

**Example**:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    userType: <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required>

    <a id="Send" 
       ng-click="myForm.$valid && userType.length() > 2 && doSomething()"></a>
</form>
```

Comment: can i check somehow if the element "<form>" has a class like ng-invalid like a conditon ?

Answer (score 3):

Handle that inside your actual function:

```
ng-click="doSomething()"

 $scope.doSomething = function() {
     if (!model.condition1 and model.condition2)
         return
     //do stuff
  }
```